# Is there something that prevents Response.Redirect to work inside try-catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, try-catch

I got some weird error with `response.redirect()` and the project wasn't building at all.. when I removed the *try-catch* block that was surrounding the block of code where `Response.Redirect()` was in it worked normally..

Just want to know if this is a known issue or something...

Comment: Can you post the code that wouldn't build?

Comment: @Fredrik: I agree most answers here can only guess at what is happening. The continued action of a threadabortexception may be related but its difficult to say without the actually error that occured and same example code.

Comment: His code doesn't even compile, why are we talking about throwing and catching ThreadAbortException?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `Response.Redirect()` throws an exception to abort the current request (`ThreadAbortedException` or something like that). So you might be catching that exception.

Edit:

This [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) describes this behavior (also for the `Request.End()` and `Server.Transfer()` methods).

For `Response.Redirect()` there exists an overload:

```
Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)
```

If you pass `endResponse=false`, then the exception is not thrown (but the runtime will continue processing the current request).

If `endResponse=true` (or if the other overload is used), the exception is thrown and the current request will immediately be terminated.

Comment: +1. Note that using non-throwing `Redirect` will continue execution of the request (or at least functions on current stack) which may case interesting side effects (i.e. persisting information or logging that would not be executed if exception is thrown). Care must be taken to not run any non-trivial code after intentional redirect.

Answer (score 4):

As Martin points out, Response.Redirect throws a ThreadAbortException. The solution is to re-throw the exception:

```
try  
{
   Response.Redirect(...);
}
catch(ThreadAbortException)
{
   throw; // EDIT: apparently this is not required :-)
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // Catch other exceptions
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to re-throw the ThreadAbortException. The runtime will automatically resurrect it anyway at the end of the catch block. See the remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

Comment: There is no need to rethrow this exception, after each try catch block has handled this exception, the exception is rethrown by the CLR anyway.  You can only stop this by calling Thread.ResetAbort() but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ok :-) But you still need to catch the ThreadAbortException separately (or check the type of the exception manually)

Comment: The KB article that Nathan Koop links has the recommended way to handle this, by calling a different overload of the Response.Redirect() method.

Answer (score 3):

Martin is correct, a ThreadAbortException gets thrown when you use a Response.Redirect, see the [kb article here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629)

Answer (score 0):

You may have referenced a variable that is declared inside the try block.

For example, the below code is invalid:

```
try
{
  var b = bool.Parse("Yeah!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (b)
  {
    Response.Redirect("somewhere else");
  }
}
```

You should move out the b declaration to outside the try-catch block.

```
var b = false;
try
{
  b = bool.Parse("Yeah!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (b)
  {
    Response.Redirect("somewhere else");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is any known issue here.

You simply can't do a Redirect() inside a try/catch block because Redirect leaves the current control to another .aspx (for instance), which leaves the catch in the air (can't come back to it).

EDIT: On the other hand, I might have had all of this figured backwards. Sorry.

Comment: That's not correct. When calling Response.Redirect(), a ThreadAbortException is thrown, which can be caught.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to think while I was typing :), my apologies.