# ASP.Net 4.5 WebForms Return Redirect to URL

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to return a redirect to URL in WebForms the same way you can in MVC. I have a simple function that returns a null if the list is empty and returns the list if there are items in the list. I want to be able to redirect to another page in the same website if the list is null.

Here is the function

```
BillContext _context = new BillContext();

public List<Models.Bill> GetBills()
{
    var bills = from b in _context.Bills
                where b.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                select b;

    if (bills.ToList().Count() < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return bills.ToList();
    }
}
```

Instead of returning null, I want to return something like this

```
return Response.Redirect("~bills/create
```

But this is not working, it is giving me a red squigly line that will not go away. This is VS2012 ASP.net WebForms Project

Comment: Are this code in same project as ASP.NET application? if so ,you are totally able to do that. Did you forgot '");' at the end of syntax? try to build and show us the exactly error

Comment: The page is in the same application and here is the error message Error 1 The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Do you have "using System.Web;" at the top of your *.cs? It should be there automatically if is an ASP.NET application, but double check it. Also, is this a ".cs" for ".aspx" file?

Comment: I have "using Systems.Web" and this is a .cs file, it is not a code behind page, it is .cs file that I added to the project.

Comment: Response.Redirect will not work in a separated class, I made an answer to show how you redirect in separated class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redirect to another aspx page like this

```
Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
```

you need to provide your page name with `.aspx` extension in end unlike that in MVC where you needed to provide the URL.

**Edited :**

```
public List<Models.Bill> GetBills()
{
    var bills = from b in _context.Bills
                where b.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                select b;

    if (bills.ToList().Count() < 1)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return bills.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated it to return Response.Redirect("CreateBill.aspx"); and still it does no like "Response" I don't know if there is a namespace I need to import

Comment: Ya, he's talking about compilation time.

Comment: try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx);` instead of `Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");`

Comment: I think that is it, I am getting a different kind of error so I consider this progress. Now I am getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BillDueDate.Models.Bill>'" I will work through this, but I think I am getting closer. Thanks a lot

Comment: it is giving such an error because you must mention `return null;` after `Response.Redirect` line

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear. I am not sure how do you expect to return something other than List (as the method's return type is defined so).

Plus, **"Response.Redirect(" just starts redirecting -- no code would be executed after its call**. [It throws ThreadAbortException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364645/why-do-i-get-a-thrown-exception-when-i-run-response-redirect).

Additionally, that looks like not correct approach in application structure at all.

But. If you would really want any kind of 'distortion' in your code, you can:

1. make the return value as 'object' and to return string with redirect url. In caller, just check if(result is string) and then redirect with that string.
2. add some ref paramenter like (... , ref Action a) and then define is as here:

   ```
   a = () =>
   {
       Response.Redirect("...");
   };
   ```

Then, the caller would check if the ref value is null and call it:

```
Action actionToCallAfterIfExists = null;
GetBills(ref actionToCallAfterIfExists);

if(actionToCallAfterIfExists != null)
{
    actionToCallAfterIfExists();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Agat I should have qualified that I am a junior developer so I admit that my approach may not be adequate. All am just doing is to create a Data access class/method that I am passing to  ASP.net ObjectDataSource.

Comment: Well, if you are trying to implement some data-service (data layer) (as separate class library), then you absolutely must not to call anything like Response.Redirect directly from there (Even if you are able with adding reference to System.Web)!!! And even do not mention the page to redirect to in the method from that library!

Answer (score 1):

The catch was: You are totally able to do `Response.Redirect()` since that was code-behind of an *.aspx file , but you are in an separated class that doesn't implement `System.Web.UI.Page`

So, in a separated class, you do redirect in this way

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~bills/create");
```

Note that is not MVC, so probally you want "~bills/create.aspx". If you want to hide extention you should look for: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite