# Response.Redirect exception inside the try/catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

Say, I have a try/catch block that encapsulates a large block of code and then somewhere in it I need to call Response.Redirect as such:

```
protected void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using(lockingMethod)
        {
            //Code...

            //Somewhere nested in the logic
            Response.Redirect(strMyNewURL);

            //More code...
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogExceptionAsError(ex);
    }
}
```

What happens in this case is that `Response.Redirect` throws an exception, something about terminating the thread, which I believe is a "normal flow of events" for that method, but it gets logged in my `LogExceptionAsError` as an error. So I was curious, is there any way to make `Response.Redirect` not throw exception?

Comment: what is value of strMyNewUrl??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something that prevents Response.Redirect to work inside try-catch block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063625/is-there-something-that-prevents-response-redirect-to-work-inside-try-catch-bloc)

Comment: @AmitSingh: Some other page in my project. I'm not sure why you need it though?

Answer (score 9):

Try with alternative version of `Response.Redirect`

```
Response.Redirect(strMyNewURL, false);
```

It will terminate the current page loading.

Comment: Evently `catch(ThreadAbortException)` will also catch it. I'm not clear though on how to handle it?

Comment: @c00000fd: I am not sure about that :(

Comment: OK. I just stepped through with a debugger. The `ThreadAbortException` is indeed caught when `Response.Redirect` is processed. So if the handler is left empty, the CLR will take over then.

Answer (score 6):

`Response.Redirect` accomplishes termination of the current execution and thus immediate redirection via throwing this exception such that it is unhandled. This is intentional and by design. You should not be catching it yourself in most cases - it defeats the purpose. If you wish to complete executing your code before redirecting, you can use the overload:

```
Response.Redirect(somewhere, false);
```

Which will NOT raise the exception. This could be inefficient unless you NEED to do something else before redirecting.

Note that this is generally an anti-pattern - controlling logic flow via exception throwing and catching... However it makes sense for this particular method to do so since a redirect usually requires no further logic to execute - just responds with a 302 and the new address to go to.

Comment: Great explanation! I have to say, though, my programming 101 teacher would have failed me if I would have use this fetching "technique". Exceptions are meant to flag bad things, not as an easy way to "drop it all and leave the room". Bad Microsoft.